# How to get the jobname from jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to get the jobname for the current build in jenkins and pass it as a parameter to an ant build script?

Comment: For me, both JOB_NAME and PROJECT_NAME return a longer version of the job name that includes the path from jenkins root.    What is the short way?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Jenkins sets some environment variables such as `JOB_NAME` (see [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables)) for more details on the variables set.

You can then access these in ant via `${env.JOB_NAME}`.

Edit: There's also a little howto for environment variables on the same page [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-AntScripts).

Answer (score 21):

A similar issue, I was looking for job name for shell script.

In the 'Execute shell' > 'Command' textbox,
both the below worked for me:

```
echo $JOB_NAME  
echo "$JOB_NAME"
```

Comment: I ran echo $JOB_NAME  on ubuntu box having jenkins installed but getting blank output

Comment: # echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/bin/phpunit:/var/lib/jenkins

Comment: I was talking about, within Jenkins, not outside the jenkins. Open Jenkins, create a job, then In the 'Execute shell' > 'Command' textbox, write the above two, both will work. Job mentioned above is within the Jenkins, not environment variable outside jenkins.

Answer (score 3):

If you can run any Job, you can easily go to the Build section of that job and go to environment variables and see all the information there.

[image]

Comment: I don't have this entry - checked on two different Jenkins installations. May be you need a plugin for this? Please clarify.

Comment: Same here - I don't have this option.

Answer (score 2):

You may set special variable for that based on global variable. Simple:

```
THEJOB="${JOB_NAME.substring(JOB_NAME.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, JOB_NAME.length())}"
```

Now $THEJOB is your job name

Comment: nice and clean way to get just the name and not the whole Jenkins folder structure in one line,  thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays there is an environment variable `JOB_BASE_NAME` which contains the last component of `JOB_NAME`.

For example: if `JOB_NAME` contains `Cool_Jobs/Very_Cool_Jobs/The_Coolest` then `JOB_BASE_NAME` will just contain `The_Coolest`

Comment: How can you print out `Very_Cool_Jobs` ? The use case is that if this is a multibranch job located within a folder then `Cool_Jobs` if the *Folder* name `Very_Cool_Jobs` is the *Job* name and `The_Coolest` is the *Branch* name, so printing Job name becomes very tricky.