# How to use Jenkins environment variable in shell script?

Tags: bash, jenkins

I want to update a java file with the jenkins build number.  I plan on using a shell script to sed the value to the correct build number.  I'm currently doing this:

```
sed -i 's/Version 3.0/Version $BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME/g'
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AndroidTest/workspace/xxx/res/values/strings.xml
```

Why doesn't this work?  I'd assume I could just use them directly.

Comment: Does the string replacement just not work, or do you get an error message, or does the 3.0 in the version get replaced with nothing ?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/41659007/984471

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) would tell you, expansions don't happen in single quotes. Use double quotes instead:

```
sed -i "s/Version 3.0/Version $BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME/g" /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AndroidTest/workspace/xxx/res/values/strings.xml
```